# Pi day is coming

Tags: bug, advertising

I know Pi day is coming but it will take another 11 months, at least.

[image: PI day add]

Although the ads are served by [adzerk](http://engine.adzerk.net) they seem to be off by a month or so. I saw ads earlier that were for events that were in the past. At that moment I assumed a one-off glitch but this one is too obvious to be considered an incident.

Can someone check with the advertisers if they intended to show and are paying for ads that are no longer relevant?

Comment: Perhaps they are advertising early for Pi approximation day.

Comment: You are thinking about the American version that's on March 14th. This add is for the European date of the 3rd day of the 14th month, Octember.

Comment: Maybe someone forgot about zero-based arrays?

Comment: Maybe in Europe April has 31 days this year: 31-4-15.

Comment: In Javascript, 3-14 is in April.

Comment: @Bart - I live in Rome and I have to disagree on your 14th month's name! U.U Earlier in the [Roman calendar](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/months/) only 10 months had names and each one of them (even now) have a meaning: Leaving out July and August (two roman emperors), **Semptember** = **Settembre(IT)** = **sette(7)** = **seven** || **October** = **Ottobre** = **otto(8)** = **eight** || **November** = **Novembre** = **nove(9)** = **nine** || **December** = **Dicembre** = **dieci(10)** = **ten** so, for correctness, the 13th month is **Undecember(11)** and the 14th is **Dodecember(12)**

Comment: @CliffBurton http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=1614831#1614831

Comment: Yes @Bart, I had guessed! And if it was not quite clear, my comment is 100% nonsense, exploit the reality to create pure nonsense!!